# Quotes get removed when prepending a string with another string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

```
random_string=" -base myinstance='localinsatnce' -variable background_interfaces='["interfaceGroup-1","interfaceGroup-2"]' -variable my_region='region-43923' "

final_String="china town $random_string"
```

The `final_string` gives the value as

```
china town -base myinstance='localinsatnce' -variable background_interfaces='[interfaceGroup-1,interfaceGroup-2]' -variable my_region='region-43923'
```

I can't escape the quotes because the `random_string` variable gets generated dynamically.

I want the quotes to be retained in the final string.

I tried this, but it does not seem to work.

```
random_string=$(sed "s/\"/\\\\\"/g" <<< $random_string)
```

Comment: If that's the actual assignment to `final_String`, it means the double quotes aren't in the value of `random_string` to begin with; whatever is generating it has to be fixed.

Comment: How exactly is the content of `random_string` generated? In a shell script? As the output of another command? How does it get into `random_string`?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Argument lists should be handled as arrays, never as strings in the first place; the FAQ in question describes building such arrays dynamically.

Comment: The righthand side of your "random_string" assignment concatenates 5 tokens. None contains embedded double-quotes, so why should there be any in the output? If there actually were any, the "final_String" value would have them.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes in random_string:

```
random_string=" -base myinstance='localinsatnce' -variable background_interfaces='[\"interfaceGroup-1\",\"interfaceGroup-2\"]' -variable my_region='region-43923' "
```